# Can't get translation using po files

Tags: php, gettext, po

I've got a translation library in my project and I am trying to show some translations but I cannot seem to get gettext to work.

Current structure looks like this:

```
Project
   test.php
   translations
      iso-3166-1
         ja.po
```

So inside Project/translations/iso-3166-1 all the .po files are stored.

In test.php I've got:

```
<?php

$locale = "ja";
$dir = "translations";

putenv("LANGUAGE=$locale");
bindtextdomain("iso-3166-1", $dir);
textdomain("iso-3166-1");

echo gettext("Australia")."\n";
```

But no matter what I try it doesn't seem to show me any translation. Using this method shouldn't it be able to look for the translation in the path that I have provided.. I've gone through the docs a few times but I can't seem to find any fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The environment variable `LANGUAGE` can hold a priority list of languages, for example `ja:fr:es` but you still have to set the environment variable `LANG` to the primary language, in your case `ja`.

But the rest of your setup also looks wrong:

- There are two directory levels missing. Your locale files should be in `translations/ja/LC_MESSAGES`.
- Translations are read from `.mo` files. You have to compile `ja.po` into `ja.mo` with the program `msgfmt` and(!) install it as `translations/ja/LC_MESSAGES/iso-3166-1.mo`.
- You are missing the call to `setlocale(LC_ALL, 'ja')`. You also don't need to modify environment variables then.

This tutorial may help you to get started: https://www.codeandweb.com/babeledit/tutorials/translation-with-gettext-and-php